# Not able to login with a Google email in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

I'm trying to login in Flutter and this is the error I'm getting when I try to login with a Google email:

```
E/flutter (26329): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
`enter code here`E/flutter (26329): Receiver: null
E/flutter (26329): Tried calling: []("email")
E/flutter (26329): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (26329): #1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42)
E/flutter (26329): #2      new User.fromDocument (package:buddiesgram/models/user.dart:23:17)
E/flutter (26329): #3      _HomePageState.saveUserInfoFirestore (package:buddiesgram/pages/HomePage.dart:83:26)
E/flutter (26329): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26329): #4      _HomePageState.controlSignIn (package:buddiesgram/pages/HomePage.dart:54:13)
E/flutter (26329): #5      _HomePageState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:buddiesgram/pages/HomePage.dart:40:9)
E/flutter (26329): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (26329): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (26329): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (26329): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (26329): #10     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:594:14)
E/flutter (26329): #11     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
E/flutter (26329): #12     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> *emphasized text*(dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
E/flutter (26329): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (26329): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (26329): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (26329): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)`**`*enter code here*`**`
E/flutter (26329): #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (26329): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (26329): #19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (26329): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (26329): #21     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (26329): #22     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (26329):
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Harshika. You'll need to provide more information such as a code snippet, when does the problem occur (sometimes / always / specific conditions) etc so that someone on the forum can help you out. Just providing the detailed error may attract downvotes/closure of the question.For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Ok! sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

#### Please include a code snippet of what you are trying to do

In my understanding of your stackTrace you are trying to call list on a null object like this:

```
final UserData userData = someObjectHere;

function login(UserData userData){
  //The problem is that userData might be null which causes your issue
  String email = userData[]("Email");
}
```

You're solution might be to use [null aware operators](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb) or to manually check whether the object you're calling a method on is not null.

```
String email = userData?.[]("Email");
```

or

```
if(userData != null) String email = userData?.[]("Email");
```